React-Spring Boot: JWT Authorization Header Always Undefined - Token Handling Issue
I am working on a full-stack project with a React frontend and Spring Boot backend.
I’m facing an issue where the Authorization header in requests is always "Bearer undefined".
This occurs when making requests from the frontend to secure API endpoints.
Here are the details:
Axios for HTTP requests and React Context (AuthProvider) to manage authentication and store the JWT token.
The backend is supposed to generate and send a JWT token upon successful login. I can confirm that the token is generated and returned from the backend.
However, the token isn't being correctly retrieved or set in the frontend, resulting in "Bearer undefined" in the Authorization header.
The backend logs an error:
JWT strings must contain exactly 2 period characters. Found: 0.
My setup:
Frontend: React with axios, useContext for authentication, and useEffect to set Axios headers globally.
Backend: Spring Boot with JwtController for authentication and a JwtAuthenticationFilter.
AuthProvider (Frontend) - Context for Managing JWT Token:
import axios from 'axios';
import { createContext, useContext, useMemo, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const AuthContext = createContext();

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [token, setToken_] = useState(() => {
        return localStorage.getItem("token") || null;
    });

    const setToken = (newToken) => {
        if (newToken) {
            localStorage.setItem('token', newToken);
            setToken_(newToken);
        } else {
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            setToken_(null);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (token) {
            console.log("Setting default Authorization header:", token);
            axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
        } else {
            delete axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"];
        }
    }, [token]);

    const contextValue = useMemo(() => ({ token, setToken }), [token]);

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);
export default AuthProvider;

LoginForm (Frontend) - User Login:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useAuth } from "../provider/authProvider";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function LoginForm() {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { setToken } = useAuth();

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/auth/login', { username, password }, {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            });
            console.log("Full response:", response);
            console.log("Response data:", response.data);

            const { jwt } = response.data;
            if (jwt) {
                setToken(jwt);
                console.log("Token set:", jwt);
                navigate('/profile');
            } else {
                console.error("JWT token is undefined or empty. Check backend response.");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error logging in!', error);
            if (error.response) {
                console.error('Error details:', error.response.data);
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <label>
                Username: <input type="text" value={username} onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} />
            </label>
            <label>
                Password: <input type="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
            </label>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
    );
}

export default LoginForm;

Backend (Spring Boot Controller):
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class JwtController {
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticate(@RequestBody AuthRequest authRequest) {
        try {
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authRequest.getUsername(), authRequest.getPassword())
            );
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("Invalid credentials");
        }

        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authRequest.getUsername());
        final String jwt = jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails);
        System.out.println("Generated JWT token: " + jwt); // Debug

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthenticationResponse(jwt));
    }
}

Backend Logs:
Authorization header: Bearer undefined
Extracted JWT token from header: undefined
JWT strings must contain exactly 2 period characters. Found: 0
# Request for Help

Why might the JWT token be "undefined" even though it seems to be generated by the backend?
Are there any known issues with localStorage, useEffect, or Axios default headers that could cause a race condition or similar?
What could be wrong with how I'm storing or setting the token in the frontend?

I tried the following:

Debugging the backend to ensure the token is generated correctly (it seems to be generating the token).

Logging the backend response in the frontend to verify if the token is being received.

Storing the token in localStorage and setting the default Axios header.

Checked CORS settings and allowed all origins and headers in the Spring Boot configuration.


What was supposed to happen:

Upon successful login, the JWT token should be set in the Authorization header for subsequent requests.

The backend should receive a valid JWT token instead of "undefined".


What actually happened:

The JWT token is not properly set, resulting in "Bearer undefined" in all requests after logging in.

The backend throws an error indicating that the JWT token is malformed or missing.



1.) Be sure to check what System.out.println("Generated JWT token: " + jwt) in your backend returns
2.) In your frontend, can you place console.log("Token set:", jwt) before the setToken(jwt) function and see what it logs?
3.) I am sure the token expected to be passed in the headers in authenticated requests is supposed to be a string type. Be sure what is being logged in number 2 above is a string. Otherwise, extract the token from the object in the frontend and send to your setToken(jwt) function.
4.) After the user logs in, check the value of the token in the localStorage to be sure it's a string. Otherwise, something is wrong in either step 1 or 2.
5.) On a final note, using typescript would help to catch bugs of this nature.
